# How do you drop a mysql table if the table name is stored as a variable?

Tags: mysql

I want to drop a table using

```
//A user is choosing the table to drop.
$name = $_POST['name'];
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die (mysql_error ());
mysql_select_db("db_name") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `$name`') or die(mysql_error());
```

If I manually replace "$name" with a table name, it works, so I believe my error has to do with with syntax around dropping a table with a name stored as a variable. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just a guess without testing, but I'd try 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $name', or else 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '.$name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, when using [single quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) ('), variables are not expanded. Use double quotes for that:

```
mysql_query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `$name`") or die(mysql_error());
```

That being said, you should not use the deprecated `mysql_` functions anymore, use MySQLi or PDO instead. Also, you are wide open to SQL injections, but I reckon you know that if you do a `DROP TABLE` with `$_POST` data, without any validation whatsoever.

Comment: @John, happy to help, but I strongly advice to reconsider your code, or at least never put it on a production system. It is extremely vulnerable.

Comment: My code validates the users input before it deletes any tables. I choose not to post it order to keep the question concise. And I'll try to switch to MySQLi, it's just hard to break habits...